# Problems with functions dealing with list of list

Tags: python

## Modify Contact

def modifyContact():

```
displayName = input('Enter a Name to search for:\n ')

afile = open('contacts.txt', 'r+')
addressList = afile.readlines()
#Using the in function to see  
for ch in addressList:
    if displayName in ch:
        print(ch)
        nameRemove = input('What do you want to replace?')
        nameModify = input('What did you want to replace it with')

        for ch in addressList:
            if ch == nameRemove:
                del addressList[ch]
                addressList.append(nameModify)
                afile.write(str(addressList))
                afile.close()
                break
```

def DeleteContact():

```
deleteName = input('Who do you want to delete?')
afile = open('contacts.txt', 'a+')
deleteList = afile.readlines()

for ch in deleteList:
    if ch in deleteName:
        deleteList.remove(ch)
        afile.write(str(deleteList))
        afile.close()   
        break
```

**When i run my code the modify function is not modifying the contact in the list and the delete function is deleting the whole document and just not the conttact **

Comment: Do you mind whittling down this code dump to something small that can be run and debug? Look at how to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

for modify part, you are not replacing the contact in the list but rather appending to it.
use: `addressList[addressList.index(ch)] = nameModify`  to replace the item in the list.

for the delete part, you opened the file in the append mode so the list contents will be appended at the end.

also `afile.write(str(list))` will write the content as `['item1', 'item2']` which may not be the format you wanted. 
If you want each element in the list to be written to the file you can use 'map'

map(afile.write, addressList)

```
def modifyContacts():
    displayName = input('Enter a Name to search for:\n ')

    afile = open('contacts.txt', 'r+')
    addressList = afile.readlines()
    #Using the in function to see  
    for ch in addressList:
        if displayName in ch:
            print(ch)
            nameRemove = input('What do you want to replace?')
            nameModify = input('What did you want to replace it with')
            print(addressList)
            print(nameRemove)
            for ch in addressList:
                if ch[:-1] == nameRemove:
                    addressList[addressList.index(ch)] = nameModify
                    print(addressList)
                    break

    afile = open('contacts.txt', 'w+')
    map(afile.write, addressList)
    afile.close()

def deleteContacts():
    deleteName = input('Who do you want to delete?')
    afile = open('contacts.txt', 'r+')
    deleteList = afile.readlines()

    print deleteList
    for ch in deleteList:
        if ch[:-1] in deleteName:
            deleteList.remove(ch)
            print deleteList
            break
    afile=open('contacts.txt', 'w+')
    map(afile.write, deleteList)
    afile.close()
```